# Select coordinates from image, based on certain criteria

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Let's say I have an OpenCV image in form of a numpy array. I want to collect all (x, y) point coordinates of points that have greater than zero blue color component. The naive way would be something like this:

```
n_rows, n_cols, _ = image.shape
points = []
for row in range(n_rows):
    for col in range(n_cols):
        if image[row, col, 0] > 0:
            points.append((row, col))
```

Is there a smarter and more efficient way to do the same, using numpy or OpenCV capabilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will help:

`np.argwhere(image[:,:,0] > 0)`

For a given `image` having three color channels (in this BGR), the `0` in `image[:,:,0]` denotes the first channel (blue)

The statement itself returns an array of coordinates where the pixel values of blue channel is greater than 0

Comment: Cool. So, it's `argwhere`. I got it by myself until `image[:,:,0] > 0`, and now the final piece of mystery is solved.